# Does stretching a spring with a relatively high spring constant value require more force because of its inertia?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, spring, inertia

Other than the fact that a spring has a relatively high spring constant (say 1000 N/m) and therefore requires more force per meter to stretch (not bend or twist).

Answer (score 1):

No, more force is required because of the higher spring constant.

If the spring with the higher spring constant happens to have more mass, then inertia will come into play, but consider the following

- you can have two springs with different spring constant and same mass
- the expansion of a spring can be done arbitrarily slowly so that inertia (which opposes changes in speed) has a diminishing effect.